# ¿Cómo modificar una parte especifica de una cadena de texto en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, consola

Deseo guardar en una variable un correo electrónico que se le ha pedido al usuario, por ejemplo

```
var = "joseluis@gmail.com" #Digamos que el usuario ingresó ese valor
```

Pero que luego tome ese correo y lo modifique despues del arroba cambiando el "gmail.com" por algúna otra cadena ya predefinida y que sea algo más asi:

```
cadena = "example.com"
var = "joseluis@" + cadena
```

O tambien podria ser algo así

```
var = "joseluis@gmail.com"

'''En este caso se deberia borrar desde el arroba 
en adelante dejando solo la extensión principal
y concatenandola con el dominio del correo'''

cadena = var + "@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno la solucion seria la siguiente, hacer un split (particion en 2 o mas partes, en este caso en dos) del string como tal:

```
(username)(@)(dominio)
```

y lo haremos con el siguiente codigo:

```
email = 'pepe@mail.com'
username = email.split('@')[0]
domain = email.split('@')[1]

print(username)
print(domain)
```

en la primera parte estara el username:

```
email.split('@')[0]
```

y en la segunda el dominio y ya de ahi en adelante sera facil manipular ambas:

```
domain = email.split('@')[1]
```

espero te ayude.

Comment: Es justo lo que buscaba muchas gracias